# Almeno and perlomeno

Tags: difference, adverbs

Collins Dictionary, and others I have checked, translate *almeno* and *perlomeno* as *at least*. It seems to me that the two words are used interchangeably in Italian writing. Am I missing any nuances?

Answer (score 4):

The Treccani dictionary indicates *[perlomeno](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/perlomeno_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)* as a synonym of *[almeno](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/almeno_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)* and viceversa, the two words can be used interchangeably.

> **almeno** /al'meno/ avv. [grafia unita della locuz. al meno]. - 1. [se
>   non altro, se non di più: *concedimi a. questo*; *vale a. mille euro*] ≈ a
>   dir poco, come minimo, **perlomeno**, quanto meno
>
> **perlomeno** /perlo'meno/ (o per lo meno) avv. [grafia unita di per lo
>   meno]. - 1. [con valore restrittivo: *il paese più vicino dista p.
>   quindici chilometri*] ≈ a dir poco, **almeno**, al minimo, quanto meno. 2.
>   [con valore limitativo: *era molto seccato, o p. così mi sembrava*] ≈
>   almeno, quanto meno, se non altro.

In the definition of almeno:

> Vale almeno/perlomeno mille euro 
> It's worth at least a thousand
>   euro

In the definition of perlomeno:

> Il paese più vicino dista perlomeno/almeno quindici chilometri
>  The
>   nearest village is at least fifteen kilometers far.

Comment: For what it's worth, they are also interchangeable in spoken speech, albeit the latter being used a bit less frequently imho.